# setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery Function Not Working When Linking FCM Delivery Data to BigQuery

Tags: kotlin, google-bigquery, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have linked the FCM delivery data to BigQuery. While the FCM delivery data has been exported to BigQuery, I set up setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery to conduct more detailed analysis, but I am unable to receive the MESSAGE_DELIVERED event. Please note, I am trying this on Android.

I'll start by explaining how I am delivering push notifications. I am using the following API to deliver push notifications.

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/{$this->projectId}/messages:send
```

Firstly, following the statement in the official documentation that says, 'This data is available when the receiving Android device has FCM SDK 18.0.1 or higher installed,' I verified the version of the FCM SDK. The version I am using is 23.0.2.

Next, I tried implementing the following two cases.

case 1:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setDeliveryMetricsExportToBigQuery(true)
```

case 2:

```
<application>
  <meta-data android:name="delivery_metrics_exported_to_big_query_enabled"
      android:value="true" />
</application>
```

In both cases, I was able to get 'MESSAGE_ACCEPTED' but was unable to get 'MESSAGE_DELIVERED'.
Please tell me what improvements are needed to receive 'MESSAGE_DELIVERED'.